# How can I get the input part to be asked one time in this code?

Tags: python, function, input, return

[my code part here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr1n7.jpg)

I need help guys.How can I get the input part to be asked one time in this code?

Comment: How can I make the asking ip part, which is the input part, asks once??

Comment: Seems like the obvious solution is to store the result in a global or class variable and only ask for input if that variable is not `None`. Also, you must post your code as text, not as screenshots, and include all relevant info in the post, not as comments.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Sorry, this is a my first time in StackOverflow. I will upload . You can click 1 , you will see my code.